# How do I use a client certificate with uzbl?

Tags: linux, browser, certificate

Simple task: I'd like to use uzbl, but I need to visit a couple of sites with client certificates. Chrome uses my local cert storage, I suppose uzbl can do that too. But how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, Linux has no such thing as "my local cert storage". Most programs just keep keys wherever they like. I think Chrome was the first to propose a database shared by several programs, the `~/.pki/nssdb`.

But `uzbl` won't use the database unless it is told to - which is highly unlikely, considering that `uzbl` does not use NSS. (`libsoup`, the HTTP library used by `uzbl`, uses GnuTLS.)

Besides, it seems that `uzbl` [doesn't even support server certificate verification](http://www.uzbl.org/bugs/index.php?do=details&task_id=213), not to mention client authentication.